# Background color of active item of navbar on Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-color

I have now this navbar:

[image: Navbar image]

But I want to remove that grey color of the background of the active item...

I'm trying with this code:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    background-color: #fff;
 }
```

And it has added the black border, but the background has not changed to white.

**UPDATE with the HTML and CSS code**

https://jsfiddle.net/v84zrhgo/ <- Code for the navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle of the fix: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/v84zrhgo/1/

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    background-color: #FFF !important;
}
```

Comment: It not works.. :( I have updated the post with the HTML and CSS for the navbar.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Thanks so much!! It works fine! but, why > a? :( I don't understand it.

Comment: a is for your <a href="#"></a> :)

Comment: Oh,,, it's true -.-" Thanks so much Andrew :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make it appear transparent so it has no color:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0) !important;
}
```